# set qt c++ mainwindow always on bottom mac osx

Tags: c++, macos, qt, window

So I am trying to set this window/ mainwindow / application in qt to always be on the bottom (like always bottom window) (so rainmeter somehow does this with their widgets), but I can't even get mac osx to do such things. 
I've tried the whole

this->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnBottomHint);

but without any luck. Any hints? Example code is amazing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got bad news and good news.  The bad news is it's simply not implemented.

The good news is: as Qt is open source, you can crack it open and take a look to know that.  And if there's a bug you can submit a fix. Here's the deal, in the generic code for `QWidget::setWindowFlags` in
[qwidget.cpp:9144](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/529b30b96435491fc6994515862f44d24efc754f/src/gui/kernel/qwidget.cpp#line9144) you have this:

```
void QWidget::setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowFlags flags)
{
    if (data->window_flags == flags)
        return;

    Q_D(QWidget);

    if ((data->window_flags | flags) & Qt::Window) {
        // the old type was a window and/or the new type is a window
        QPoint oldPos = pos();
        bool visible = isVisible();
        setParent(parentWidget(), flags);

        // if both types are windows or neither of them are, we restore
        // the old position
        if (!((data->window_flags ^ flags) & Qt::Window)
            && (visible || testAttribute(Qt::WA_Moved))) {
            move(oldPos);
        }
        // for backward-compatibility we change Qt::WA_QuitOnClose attribute value only when the window was recreated.
        d->adjustQuitOnCloseAttribute();
    } else {
        data->window_flags = flags;
    }
}
```

So essentially it just sets `window_flags`.  The mac behavior of QWidget is in [qwidget_mac.mm](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/gui/kernel/qwidget_mac.mm).

And you will find no reference to `Qt::WindowStaysOnBottomHint` in that file. *(You'll find `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` though...)*

I'll stop at saying *"not possible unless you either patch Qt, or otherwise go beneath Qt"*.

Patching `qwidget_mac.mm` is left as an exercise to the reader.  :-)

Comment: Sucky.  But...in Qt's defense, though: I will point out that it does say "Hint".  Which is a way of saying *"I'd like this to be true if it could be"*...